# How to make the dictionary.Item into a key for another dictionary and keep the new key also

Tags: python, dictionary

I have scenario A a dictionary that I would wish to transform using this method if it's possible or is there an alternative

```
A = {A:1,B:2,C:3}

B =  {values[1] : values[1]*2 for values in A.items()}
```

Desired outcome:

```
B = {1:2,2:4,3:6}
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem? You seem to have a solution that works (except you should just use `A.values()` instead of `A.items()`)

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
A = (1,2,3)
B = {item:item*2 for item in A}
```

If you still want a dictionary A, could be:

```
A = {'A':1, 'B':2, 'C':3}
B = {item[1]:item[1]*2 for item in A.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

`B = {val:val*2 for val in A.values()}`.

Ordered dicts are only ensured >= Python3.7 so while this will likely work in Python < 3.7 it would be bad practice not to use an OrderedDict or list. Also, items in the construct of dictionaries are a dict method yielding a dict_items class so is slightly misleading to use as an iterator variable name. In the future, SO appreciates using working code examples as your input does not (`A:1` vs `"A"`) etc. ;)